# C++ sorting container of base class pointers to derived objects

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an std::list of base class pointers, all of which point to one of the two derived object classes. An instance of the base class is never declared, and, although the base class is not abstract, every member function is declared as virtual. Consider the code below:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ...
    //member functions
    ...

protected:
    int common_data_1;
    std::string common_data_2;
    ...
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B();
    //member functions
    ...

protected:
    std::string class_B_specific_data;
    ...
};

class C: public A
{
public:
    C();
    //member functions
    ...

protected:
    std::string class_C_specific_data;
    ...
};
```

These classes are instantiated as the appropriate base class via conditional statements and stored in an std::list by the base class pointer simultaneously in the same block of code like so:

```
std::list<A*> ptrList;

//conditional statements either create a B or C object
//and then that object is appended to the list

if (blahblah = true)
    A* entry = new B();
else
    A* entry = new C();

ptrList.append(entry);
```

I need to perform an insertion sort on this container of base class pointers based on an integer value that both derived classes inherit; however, in my previous attempts and upon inspection with a debugger tool, I find that my insertion sort algorithm properly makes the correct comparisons when accessing the integer that the comparison is based on, but I am **unable to swap the position of the base class pointers** in the std::list. I want to sort this container of pointers so that I can easily print the data in the proper order with a simple for loop.

This is clearly the result of a misunderstanding of pointer semantics, but to much avail I have been unable to find any reference or example that elucidates or solves the issue I am experiencing.

Any result that I have found either on this site or elsewhere solves this problem by using a container of the actual objects instead of a container of pointers to the objects. But, in my case, I can't do this because my code relies on the polymorphic behavior of the base class in order to have one big list of derived objects, instead of multiple lists for each derived object. Obviously, this makes calling member functions of the correct derived class extremely easy, and I would rather not redesign the entire structure of my data if I can avoid it.

If requested, I can post snippets of my code and/or the attempts that I have made to properly swap these pointer positions inside the container; however, I am unsure if this would even be helpful, since I am clearly using the wrong syntax to handle the pointers.

I appreciate any feedback; this problem has been plaguing me for the past few weeks and it is definitely time for me to step back and ask for assistance. I have a feeling that I am over-analyzing this issue, and that is most likely what is preventing me from solving the problem.

Comment: Do you need to perform insertion sort on the container, or do you need to sort the container?

Comment: Stop using `std::list`.  No, really.  It is almost never a good idea.  Second, please provide actual code that caused the problem -- in this case, a call to `std::sort`, and the types of the variables.  Ideally a SSCCE -- an actual bit of code that demonstrates something going wrong, not pseudo code that contains what you think is important; if you understood what was important, you wouldn't be asking for help.  You can, however, simplify your code, TEST that it still generates the problem, and repeat until your code is short, without understanding what is important (because you can TEST).

Comment: Showing the code that actually exhibits the problem is a good idea.

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's unclear what you're trying to do and what the problem is, but, with that said, using `std::list::sort()` with a lambda expression as an argument is my preferred way to sort a collection of pointers, in which you're using some data member of the pointed-to objects as a sorting criteria.

Comment: You say that you are unable to swap elements in a list; if that is the case, then you are definitely doing something wrong, and I advise you to clear that up whether or not you get a working sorter along the way.

Comment: Sorry to all of those that are requesting my exact code; I didn't have access to it yesterday when I made this post. I'm going to try a few of these suggestions, and I'll post my code if I run into trouble again

Comment: Also, Yakk, is there any reason you can provide to actually discourage me from using std::list? I don't really see an advantage of using std::vector or something else in my case. It is extremely efficient in terms of appending information to the container when I read my data in, and I never need to directly access specific positions in the list by an index value. And when I want to write my data from that container, I iterate through the entire list anyway

Comment: also,  @juanchopanza, I want to sort all of the elements in the container from least to greatest based on the inherited integer; I just figured that an insertion sort is probably the most logical and simple choice. I didn't think to use the std::list::sort function because I couldn't get the std::sort function to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to sort an existing container, `sort` has a `Compare comp` argument that allows your to change its default behavior. To use it, you define a functor (a class that overrides `operator()`) that knows how you want your pointers to be compared. In this case, you want to define one that compares the `common_data_1` that the pointed-to objects have.

```
class Comparator {
  public:
    bool operator(A* left, A* right) {
        //You can do whatever logic you need here, here's an example:
        return (a->common_data_1) < (b->common_data_2);
    }
}
```

Then, call `sort` on your list:

```
ptrList.sort(Comparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @IanPudney's answer, though I typically use a lambda:

```
ptrList.sort([](A* first, A* second)
               {return first->common_data_1 < second->common_data_1;}
            );
```

Replace `common_data_1` with whatever data member or function you want to use to sort.